# What is the difference between Function() and Function in dart?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

While declaring a **Function member in a class** we can do both;

```
Function first;
Function() second;
```

#### What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- `Function` represents any function:

```dart
void function() {}
int anotherFunction(int positional, {String named}) {}


Function example = function; // works
example = anotherFunction; // works too
```

- `Function()` represents a function with no parameter:

```dart
void function() {}
int anotherFunction(int positional, {String named}) {}


Function() example = function; // works
example = anotherFunction; // doesn't compile. anotherFunction has parameters
```

A variant of `Function()` could be:

```dart
void Function() example;
```

Similarly, we can specify parameters for our function:

```dart
void function() {}
int anotherFunction(int positional, {String named}) {}

int Function(int, {String named}) example;

example = function; // Doesn't work, function doesn't match the type defined
example = anotherFunction; // works
```

Answer (score 0):

Practical Example of it,

We have method `callMe`() which will be called by `RaisedButton`

```
 void callMe() {
    print('Call Me');
  }
```

**RaisedButton Code:**

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: callMe, // its working even if we called another method from here
        child: Text('Pressed Me '),
      ),
```

If `callMe`() method have param then it will not works as Function(param) required to be called from Function which have params

```
void callMe(String title) {
        print('Call Me');
      }
```

**RaisedButton with Function Code:**

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          callMe('sample'); 
        },
        child: Text('Pressed Me '),
      ),
```